# Extracting Links from dynamic website using Java

Tags: java, html-parsing, web-crawler, jsoup

I'm trying to extract all the links from a website. I used Jsoup in previous programs to do this, the problem here is that "more content" is generated by pressing the more button and it doesn't change pages, it simply loads more content so I'm not sure how to see all of the available links using Java and Jsoup.

The website is http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/msft and I'm simply trying to extract all the links to articles for a specific company, such as Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get yourself something you can spy on the requests you're making over the wire. You could watch the http traffic using the Network tab in Chrome, but personally I like Charles. Anyway, if you check out what happens when you click the more button you would see that a POST request is being made (using AJAX of course) the looks like this:

http://seekingalpha.com/account/ajax_headlines_content  200 POST    seekingalpha.com    /account/ajax_headlines_content  432 ms 5.94 KB Complete

In the headers the params are:

type    all
page    2
slugs   msft
is_symbol_page  true

So if I were you I'd just emulate that by making the POST request with the page param counting up until you've got all the content you want. By the way the content returned was an html fragment so easy to parse, eg:

```
> <div class="symbol_articles_list mini_category">
>     <div>
>       <ul>
>           <li>
>               <div class="fl">
>                 <a class="small_picture" href="/author/the-part-time-investor">
>                   <img height="20" width="20" src="http://static1.cdn-seekingalpha.com/images/users_profile/000/541/113/small_pic.png?1352646193"/>
>                 </a>
>               </div>
>             <div class="content">
>               <div class="symbol_article">
>                 <a href="/article/1109901-microsoft-and-4-other-undervalued-stocks"
> sasource="portfolio_rel">Microsoft And 4 Other Undervalued Stocks</a>
>                 <div class="date_on_by">
>                     <a sasource="portfolio_rel" href="/author/the-part-time-investor">The Part-time Investor</a>
>                   <span class="bullet">&bull;</span>
>                   Mon, Jan 14<span class='bullet'>&bull;</span> <span class='comments'><a
> href='/article/1109901-microsoft-and-4-other-undervalued-stocks#comments_header'
> sasource='headlines_tabs'>44&nbsp;Comments</a></span>               
> </div>
>               </div>
>             </div>
>             <div class="cleaner"></div>
>           </li>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer! Could you please elaborate on what you mean by 

"just emulate that by making the POST request with the page param counting up " . I've never done this before so I'm not sure how to emulate a POST request with specific parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry I've never used Jsoup before, but looking at the java doc I think you'd do this: Jsoup.connect("http://seekingalpha.com/account/ajax_headlines_content").data("type", "all").data("page", "2").data("slugs","msft").data("is_symbol_page","true").post();

Answer (score 0):

I would use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). extract the displayed links and than click on 'more' (HtmlUnit will execute the javascript that loads more links) )and extract the new shown links